# Yii query result cuts off alias

Tags: postgresql, yii

I have a pretty long alias in my query but I don't think it is above the allowed limit. I am using a Postgres database and and Yii 1.1.15.  The query runs fine and returns the correct values but my result cuts off the alias in the result array.

This is my query:

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
          ->select("mytable AS How many production lines at your company/division/location will require")
          ->from($table);
$result = $query->query();
```

My result looks like this:

```
$result = array(
  array('How many production lines at your company/division/location wil' => string(18) "None/doesn't apply"),
  array('How many production lines at your company/division/location wil' => string(18) "None"),
  .....
);
```

Notice that my result array has a key of "How many production lines at your company/division/location wil" instead of "How many production lines at your company/division/location will require"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same query directly in the database and I seen the same problem.

It turns out that there is a 64 byte limit on the column name.  I read that there is a way to increase it but that would require a recompile.

To increase change the NAMEDATALEN constant in src/include/pg_config_manual.h and recompile.